# VSTS - Cannot approve release

Tags: release, release-management, ms-release-management, azure-devops

I understand that VSTS Release is still not under final version, but I am stuck with a problem. When there is a pending approval, sometimes it is simply not possible to approve/reject the release. Example:

[image]
As you can see I have 3 environments: DEV, QA and PROD. When deploying to DEV, there is no approval required. So now it shows "In Progress" but an approval is waiting.

[image]
On the picture above is a proof that we are waiting for the Post deployment approval.

[image]
Finally, you can see above that I configured myself to receive notification for approval and to be an approver.

Any idea?

**[UPDATE]**
The above shows that I could approve pre-deployment to QA (DEV here was auto-approved), and now I cannot approve the post-deployment to QA.

Here is a screenshot of a successful release (only on DEV environment though), and having the same warning message:

> Cannot update deployment status for (web app name) -
>   {"Message":"Repository could not be found."}

[image]

Comment: The warnings in that first screenshot make it look like there may have been a problem with the release service.

Comment: Can you share the detailed warning message? And when does the message display? Before or after you click "Approve or Reject?

Comment: Daniel and Eddie, please see the updated initial post. @DanielMann, any idea how to solve this warning message? Eddie, the message is **not** displayed but it should be, because there is a pending post-deployment approval to do.

Comment: I have the same problem: the release is displaying the same warning message at the end of step [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/SuVtcyg.png)

Comment: The warning message is generated by "Deploy Website to Azure" step. Can you check if the deployment can be finished successfully with auto approve?

Comment: According to the logs, the deployment was successful. You can check them here: http://pastebin.com/xCztTtqC

Comment: Does the approve dialog pop up if check "Continue on error" option on "Deploy Website to Azure" step? And add a "system.debug" variable and set the value to "true" and execute the release again to get a detailed logs.

Comment: The warning message is apparently not important https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5deaf697-1e83-43b6-9e03-cd08a2657165/azure-website-deployment-task-my-release-passed-with-some-warning?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have a prior release candidate that we are not going to deploy to prod, it looks like this:

[image: Release Pipeline]

Note this is in the new Azure DevOps UI for VSTS/TFS builds and releases.  This shows, chronologically from the bottom up, two releases deployed to prod, then a third release not deployed to Prod, then a fourth release (at top), which cannot be deployed to prod until the third release is rejected or cancelled. Both will work but in my experience the release tracking is a little cleaner if you reject the release rather than cancel it.

To do this, click "Pending approval" in the third release Prod environment to view approvals and then click Reject. If you have multiple prior releases not deployed to Prod you will need to reject or cancel them all - again my preference is to reject them chronologically (from first undeployed release near the bottom towards the last undeployed release near the top).

Once done, the release at the top will no longer appear as queued and you will be able to approve it (assuming you have enabled Pre-deployment approvals for approving deployment to Prod) to allow deployment to commence.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go into the release and cancel all previously queued releases. In your first screenshot under environments, each environment should be a hyperlink. Select that one in question and under Waiting for Deployment, you can cancel all the ones you don't want. That will clear up the queue.

Comment: Just ran into this issue today, so hard to find and seems there is a workflow to improve here