# Unable to approve latest release Azure devOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

I have auto run build and release pipeline in Team service.

It start whenever developer check in code in repository.

​In release pipeline I set approver name (Pre-deployment approvals) to approve deployment on target server.

​In deployment queue setting I used

​specific for 'Number of parallel deployments' ,

1 for Maximum number of parallel deployments,

​Deploy latest and cancel the others for 'subsequent releases'

​
​In my case developer check-in multiple times and auto start pipelines create queue for release approvals.

​
​Approver want to approve latest one and want auto cancel all previous one as shown in image.

​but system forced him to approve one pending one only.

​
​Please assist.​

I tried to change deployment queue setting[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you approve also contain post deployment approval for your release, **Deploy latest and cancel the others** that it does **not cancel for post deployment approvals** and that's by design.

You need to go into the release and manually reject/cancel all previously queued releases.

Please take a look at below similar issues here：

- [Release pipleline "Deploy latest and cancel the others" not working](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/364219/release-pipleline-deploy-latest-and-cancel-the-oth.html)
- [VSTS - Cannot approve release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134076/vsts-cannot-approve-release)

If you are only using pre deployment approvals, try to reject the first in the queue and refresh the page, which may do the trick. For example:  If you go to the main page for the release definition and see a queue of releases waiting for deployment:

[image]

Click on the first one and reject it, then refresh the list. Only the last release remains queued:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I checked on MS docs.. All suggested for manual cancel previous one.